Error when I use flutter run in android studio... Execution failed for task ':camera_android_camerax:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
I am very new to flutter and Android Studio
When I use flutter run this error shows up.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':camera_android_camerax:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':camera_android_camerax:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-34\core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\jlink.exe with arguments {--module-path C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\tra
nsforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\temp\jmod --add-modules java.base --output C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\4a46fc89ed5f9adfe3afebf74eb8bfeb\transformed\output\jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             15.7s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1


I tried a lot of solutions from chatgpt.
cleared gradle cache.
changed targetSdkversion and compileSdkversion from 34 to 31 then back to 34.
manually overrode many dependencies.
and more
